# AutoHotKey, Foxit, PHP

Tags: autohotkey, foxit-reader

I'm trying to print same PDF lables that are generated with PHP and Mysql.

The creation of the PDF file is done and working. I save the pdf on a temp folder.
and then i run this Autohotkey script:

```
#Persistent 
SetTimer, PrintMon, 5000 ;every 5 seconds return
PrintMon:
IfExist C:\rolls\temp\*.pdf
  {
   runwait, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /p "C:\rolls\temp\%A_LoopFileName%",,min 
}
FileDelete, C:\rolls\temp\*.pdf
Process, Close, foxitreader.exe
return
```

I need to close the Foxit program before i can generate and print another PDF file.

I've tried "Process, Close, foxitreader.exe"
And "Winclose, Start - Foxit Reader",

but still no luck.

Hope someone can help me on this one,

Thanks

Comment: additional to ahkcoder's answer, you might want to use `WinWaitClose` here

Comment: did not work, but thanks any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to keep working, even with foxit open.

On Foxit goto file ->preferences->general and disable everything.
On autohotkey script Change

```
runwait, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /p "C:\rolls\temp\%A_LoopFileName%",,min
```

With

```
runwait, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /p "C:\rolls\temp\%A_LoopFileName%",,hide
```

and Remove the

```
Process, Close, foxitreader.exe
```

Final Code:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, PrintMon, 5000 ;every 5 seconds return
PrintMon:
IfExist C:\rolls\temp\*.pdf
{
runwait, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /p "C:\rolls\temp\%A_LoopFileName%",,hide
}
FileDelete, C:\rolls\temp\*.pdf
return
```

And there you have a way to auto print from PHP using AutoHotKey and Foxit Reader

Update:
New version on Foxit as a problem with the silent print.
Use version 6.23 for now.

[Foxit Reader 6.23](http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/reader/desktop/win/6.x/6.2/enu/FoxitReader623.815_enu_Setup.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
; Hard close
WinKill, Start - Foxit Reader
```

Comment: the problem was with the last version of foxit.